# Alter a form based on where it is called from

Tags: views, forms

I am using something on the lines of

```
  $view = views_get_current_view();
  $build = drupal_get_form("comment_node_contenttype_form", 
  (object) array('nid' => $view-> args[0])); 
  print render($build);
```

to print a comment form in my views.

My challenge is I am using the same code in two different displays. I need to make a few fields in the comment form required only when it is getting called from a particular display.

Comment: Bit hacky, but you could easily stuff some context onto the node object

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.

```
  if ($form_id == 'comment_node_CONTENT_TYPE_form') {
    $view = views_get_current_view();
    if ($view->current_display == 'block_1') {
      //Alter my form
    }
  }
```

I checked [views_get_current_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_current_view/7) function. Since it is using caching there is no harm in calling it again.